# Remove blank spaces (trim) in result retrieved using JpaRepository

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot

The Repository class is:

```
public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Category,Integer> {
}
```

The service class is:

```
@Service
public class CategoriesService {

    @Autowired
    CategoryRepository repo;

    public Iterable<Category> findAll(){
        return repo.findAll();
    }
}
```

Then i'm using `service.findAll()` to retrieve the result ArrayList. It give me correct result but since values in database contains blank space. So how can i remove that blank spaces in results in the ArrayList.(Without iterating the result arrayList and modify)

**Edited**
The problem is until we get arrayList in service class we have no access to the individual data elements.

Comment: you mean to trim the leading and trailing spaces in your result or remove the result that contains blank space

Comment: you mean the first one or second in my comment

Comment: @vineethsivan , sorry, it's first one. The problem is until we get arrayList in service class we have no access to the individual data.

Comment: I don't think you can achieve this without iterating the list.

Answer (score 0):

> So how can i remove that blanck spaces in results in the ArrayList.(Without iterating the result arrayList and modify)

One way is to modify your query and get the correct result set with no leading or trailing spaces. You can use functions like `LTRIM` and `RTRIM`.

1. RTRIM – Removes the Spaces on the right side (or leading spaces) of the string
2. LTRIM – Removes the Spaces on the left side (or trailing spaces) of the string

Here is a query example:

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(User_Name)) AS User_Name FROM Users
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `findAll()` method,when you are retrieving the value from database and before adding them in ArrayList you can call the `trim()`.And if you are using `ArrayList.toString()` then dont rely on this write your own method for formatting your ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

The JPA module supports defining a query manually as String or have it being derived from the method name. As you've currently implemented `findAll()` it derives the query automatically.  Although getting a query derived from the method name is quite convenient, one might face the situation in which either the method name parser does not support the keyword one wants to use or the method name would get unnecessarily ugly. So you can either use JPA named queries through a naming convention or annotate your query method with @Query.  An example of the latter that trims the leading and trailing whitespace would look something like this:

```
public CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Category,Integer> {
@Query("SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(Category_Field)) AS Category_Field FROM Categories")
  User findAll();
}
```

If you still have questions you can read more about custom JPA queries here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html